getting org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SQL state [HY109]; error code [-99999]; Cursor position not valid
I am getting the below exception whenever i run a method which run the following query.
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [   SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME WHERE  TYPESERV = 'INPUT VAUE'
]; SQL state [HY109]; error code [-99999]; Cursor position not valid.
    public String getType(String name, String service) {

    final var parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("service", service);

    final var query = """
                SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME WHERE  TYPESERV = :service
            """;
    return this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate(name)
            .query( query, new MapSqlParameterSource(parameters), rs -> {
                    return rs.getString("FIELD_NAME");
            }
    );
    

complete log:
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME WHERE  TYPESERV = ? ]; SQL state [HY109]; error code [-99999]; Cursor position not valid.
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1549)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:748)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:178)
.....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cursor position not valid.
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:982)
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:435)
at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:412)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getValue(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3770)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3411)
at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3438)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java)

Updates:
driverClassName: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
i-series dbversion= 7.4.0
library=net.sf.jt400,
version of jt400 driver = 20.0.7

driverClassName: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
dbversion= 7.4.0
library=net.sf.jt400, ver= 20.0.7

Looks like the ResultSet was empty, i.e. your query returned no results.  I get a similiar error when attempting to access a row after rs.next() returned false.
java.sql.SQLException: Cursor position not valid.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.createSQLExceptionSubClass(JDError.java:978)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:431)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:408)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getValue(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3984)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3614)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCResultSet.getString(AS400JDBCResultSet.java:3643)


that is not the case here, I have run this particular query using the dbeaver tool and gotten result for the inputs I have given.  I also tried different inputs in case it only coming in some specific records but no, that is not the case here too. The same query when ran in dbeaver works and when hardcoded in code still fails.
